# does file_get_contents("php://input"); method have any race conditions? And, does it block if multiple request are made?

Tags: php

When multiple users access the page in php which has file_get_contents("php://input"); method will there be any blocking? I understand that each request makes an new instance, Does the above method makes any blocking on the requests made? Does it use only one stream for all the instances or different stream for different request? I am new to php so please help me in this...

Comment: "Race conditions?" - I guess the question aims at whether multiple php instances are "isolated" from each other. The answer (in general) is: yes, each request is handled by its own php instance each having its own set of input/output streams. But whether there's _some_ blocking in _any arbitrary_ environment possible, is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question can you please look in to it and give some inputs.@Daan and @volkerk

Comment: I'm not comfortable with giving you a _definite_ answer. There might be (subtle) real life conditions under which there will be some sort of blocking depending on the setup. But....php is clearly not limited to handling multiple input request (...streams) sequentially. I've just tested it with 20 concurrent POST requests each having a request body of ~40MB and they were handled in parallel. (And I would have been really surprised if they hadn't been. Not so much, if e.g. 16 would have been handled at a time and 4 been stalled; but that didn't happen in my setup.)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am dealing with JSONObject for my app. In any case the data may not exceed few KB or 2 or 3 MB. So i can use this method. Your comment help me so much. @Volkerk

Comment: But if you have a setup where scaling really can be an issue I urge you to ask the good people over at  serverfault.com. Here you're asking (in theory) developers, there you get information about when the rubber meets the road ;-) For me (as a developer not looking left or right) a directory can have subdirectories, period. Then my appliation hits an ext2 file system and suddenly 31998 subdirectories is a hard limit and my application becomes slooooooow way before that.

Comment: I have posted this on serverfault.com. You have introduced me to the new service.@VolkerK